# PHP: index operations inside query possible?

Tags: php, indexing, operation

I have an array ($updateInputs) with 6 elements, 6 / 2 which each 3 belong to a single row in a database table. What I'm trying to do is put a query in a while loop so that every iteration, the index will be correctly placed for the next 3 elements. $i starts at 0 and gets + 1 every loop. I'm trying to do the following but it just crashes my website:

```
$tempMult = $i*3;
$updatedInputs = $_REQUEST['UPDATEDtoy'];
$query = "UPDATE TOY 
        SET TOYID='$updatedInputs[0 + $tempMult]', TOYName='$updatedInputs[1 + $tempMult]', TOYprice='$updatedInputs[2 + $tempMult]',
        TOYmanufacturer='$updatedInputs[3 + $tempMult]'
        WHERE TOYID='$exactID[$i]'";
```

Is there another way to go about this? I just need it so that the second loop, the index will start at 3->4->5. I assume it isn't possible to do operations inside queries? Any help is appreciated

EDIT (full version):
this is what gets returned when I use

```
print_r($updatedInputs);
$tempMult = $i*6;
echo "$tempMult <br>";
```

I get :

Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => moo1 ) Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5 [5] => foo6 [6] => moo1 [7] => moo2 [8] => moo3 [9] => moo4 [10] => moo5 [11] => moo6 ) 0

Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5 [5] => foo6 [6] => moo1 [7] => moo2 [8] => moo3 [9] => moo4 [10] => moo5 [11] => moo6 ) 6

as you can see, 0 and 6 is correct (in the case of 12 elements). It gets printed twice because there are 2 loops

EDIT2 (temporary NOOB solution):

I'm just going to use this as a temporary noobie solution until I see an answer:

```
$a = 0 + $i*6;
$b = 1 + $i*6;
$c = 2 + $i*6;
$d = 3 + $i*6;
$e = 4 + $i*6;
$f = 5 + $i*6; 

$updatedInputs = $_REQUEST['UPDATEDtoy'];
$query = "UPDATE TOY 
SET TOYID='$updatedInputs[$a]', TOYName='$updatedInputs[$b]' ...
WHERE TOYID='$exactID[$i]'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: "crashes my website" unlikely, do you check for errors?

Comment: are you sure $updatedInputs has index `0 + $tempMult`  ? what are you getting when you echo the $query and var_dump($updatedInputs ) ?

Comment: @Dagon yes everything works fine until i put + $tempMult. I get Server Error

Comment: @NullPoiиteя yes I am sure it starts at zero. When i print_r and var_dump $updateInputs, I get Array([0]=>.. [1]=>..and all my elements in the array

Comment: can you add what exactly are you getting .. in question .. so i can help you

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I have shortened my original question for the sake of simplicity but here is exactly what i get when i print_r         Array ( [0] => foo1 [1] => foo2 [2] => foo3 [3] => foo4 [4] => foo5 [5] => foo6 [6] => moo1 [7] => moo2 [8] => moo3 [9] => moo4 [10] => moo5 [11] => moo6 )

Comment: you can add ... we would love to see a question which have more information over simple question with less informaiton

Comment: what is in $tempMult ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I have added an edit with the returned values

Answer (score -1):

Use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).  See the examples in the link.  You just need to  pass the already computed variables to PDO and it will automatically insert them into your query.

Comment: I'm not going to post an answer that will get him hacked via SQL injection (which is exactly what the original code is setup for).

Comment: i am just disagree that using mysq_* is not safe .. those are as safe as pdo